# Angularjs, how to display DateTime in cshtml

Tags: angularjs, datetime, razor

I wrote a piece of code for getting a list of record from db and put them in $scope.records.

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);
app.controller('MyAppController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http({ method: 'GET', url: '/Api/GetRecord' }).
           success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
               $scope.records = data;
           }).
           error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
               alert(data);
           });
}]);
```

Then, I want to display the records like below.

```
<div ng-repeat="record in records">
   <div>{{record.ID}}</div>
   <div>{{record.SubmitDate}}</div>
   <div>{{record.Status}}</div>
</div>
```

The ID and status are shown correctly. However, the submit dates cannot show probably.The submit date is "2016-08-30 09:59:17.080" in db but all the submit dates become "/Date(1472522357080)/" while displaying in the website.

How can I display the datetime correctly? Thanks.

Comment: {{record.SubmitDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z'}}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try with date filter

```
{{1288323623006 | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z'}}
```

or

```
{{record.SubmitDate.replace('/Date(','').replace(')/','') | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z'}}
```

Comment: Sorry but seems that it does not work. It still display "/Date(1472522357080)/" instead of a readable DateTime.

Comment: @Natsuki_Kato Could you please console.log($scope.records)? What's the data format?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It works when I try the second solution.

Comment: Great. Happy coding:-)

Answer (score 0):

Try the new Date function as
$scope.date = new Date (1472522357080);
and bind the same $scope.date variable as ng-model to the date control.