# Get datetime in Angularjs - Loading content from Get url

Tags: angularjs

**I have complete its here**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39221731/6688824

This is how I make `ng-repeat` to your content, but when it is that I must have printed date you will see it like this.

Error:

> /Date(1475859014037)/

What I'd like to get it to be, it was 31-12-2016 How to date was easy and read fast and simple. However, I have tried this:

```
{{KundeValue.BuyTime | date: 'dd-mm-yyyy'}}
```

The problem is that it is the date that supports and creates problems in relation to which I would want to do. All other content that I have made in my `ng-repeat` works just fine but it is just date that supports and gives me problems for date

**EIDT**

```
var app = angular.module('AllKunder', []);
app.controller('KundeList', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.totalDisplayed = 50;

    $scope.change = function () {
        $scope.totalDisplayed += 25;
    }

    var url = "/JsonClass/ListUser";

    $http.get(url).success( function(response) {
        $scope.KundeList = response;
        console.log("GET Url")
    });

})
```

Comment: your date input is a string containing `/Date(1475859014037)/`?

Comment: @Jorg yea, but i have complete its now. After i see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39221487/angularjs-how-to-display-datetime-in-cshtml/39221731#39221731

Answer (score -1):

the best way is to use momentjs and his angular integration : https://github.com/urish/angular-moment

the filters plugins are powerful and easy to use.